# permissions for phing.php on Ubuntu for execution in Eclipse

Tags: phing

I installed phing via apt-get on my Ubuntu machine. Then I set up phing as external program in Eclipse but now I am facing a permission problem.

Giving phing.php a different owner did not help. I still get:

```
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "/usr/share/php/phing.php" 
(in directory "/var/www/html/fullerweb"): error=13, Permission denied
```

What permissions are needed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `/usr/bin/phing` instead.